# Can hudson send an email when a slave executor is offline

Tags: plugins, hudson, slave

At my company we run Hudson with 8 slave build machines.  Sometimes, these slaves will go offline and need restarting.  If no-one is looking at the Hudson web page, this can go unnoticed.

Is there a way to send an email to someone when a slave goes offline?  I can't seem to find a relevant plug-in in the list.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you should consider using the [email-ext plugin](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Email-ext+plugin)

Bye!

Comment: That plug-in only seems to support failing builds.  I need something to trigger on failing build /executors/.